# Name Can Be Simplified - C# - XmlAttributeAttribute Class - IDE0001

Tags: c#, xml, xml-attribute

When using the ***XmlAttributeAttribute*** class in C#, I'm told that the class name ***XmlAttributeAttribute*** can be simplified to ***XmlAttribute***.

I'm unsure how this works exactly. How am I permitted to refer to a class by a shortened name? How does C# know that this is valid? I can not see this referenced in any documentation.

Also, does this rule apply to other classes/components within the C# environment?

Comment: Regardless of being a duplicate, **XmlAttributeAttribute** sounds horrible.

Comment: It is called out as a note in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653979.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply.

Answer (score 2):

> I can not see this referenced in any documentation.

Really? did you see the MSDN documentation for [XmlAttributeAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). It clearly says:

> Note: You can use the word XmlAttribute in your code instead of the
>   longer XmlAttributeAttribute.

To address your Second question

> Also, does this rule apply to other classes/components within the C#
>   environment?

Yes it does, in whichever situation compiler can infer it; you don't need to be explicit. For example, if you have defined a generic function like

```
public void method<T>(T arg, string arg1)
{
  // some code
}
```

You can just call the function saying below cause it can infer the type from the first parameter which is of type `T`

```
string str1 = "test";
method(str1, null);
```

Instead of being explicit and calling like

```
method<string>(str1, null);
```

You will get the same kind of info message *name can be simplified*

Comment: Thank you - I saw this too, just after I posted. I must have missed it the first time.